# HOMEBREW PYSIDE2 - It is not recognizable by python

Tags: pyside2

I installed `pyside2` through *homebrew*. It installs *python10*.

I confirmed that *python10* is working bu `python3 --version`

But i get an error when importing *pyside2* in python console.

[image]

Is there something that i miss?

many thanks.
m1, osx 12.6.1